# How many calcium ions is needed to displace hydronium ions in an strong acid ion exchange resin?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

If 1 mole of Ca2+ can displace 2 moles of Na+ in an ion exchange resin, can it do the same for H+? Will Ca2+ ion displace 2 moles of H+ in a strong acid resin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes, as  $\ce{1 Ca^2+}$ displaces $\ce{2 H+}$.

No, as you need to involve more then $\ce{1 Ca^2+}$ to displace $\ce{2 H+}$ for exchange comparable with ionex capacity, as some  $\ce{Ca^2+}$ passes through before $\ce{H+}$ is washed out.

Comment: I see. So to completely wash out the H+ ion in the solution, Ca2+ needed to be in excess? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are. But not in so big excess as  opposite, i.e. washing out calcium. Strong catexes prefer calcium to hydrogen, in contrary to weak catexes..

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot on my exam.

Comment: It should not. Using SE to solve exam tasks is a bad way to use it.

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlaying principles. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you, and that the Q/A is beneficial for broad audience.
 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. It can be self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.

Comment: This was not a homework, our professor taught us how to do calculations for Ion exchange resins. However, he did not showed us how to calculate for the stoichiometry of divalent cations with monovalent cations. I am reading materials online and saw an example that has H+ embedded on the resin instead of Na+ so I used SE to know if the stoichiomrtry between Ca and Na also applies for H

Comment: "not literally". The key part is you have not provided any own reasoning, what is a no no in Chem SE.     Why should the stoichiometry be different between free and bound functional groups ?

Comment: Because prior in posting my question here, I asked quora first and one response to my question is that the stoichiometry of Ca2+ ion to H+ is 1:1 and that confused me a lot. So I went to SE to see if my thoughts are incorrect or not.